# Generating an offscreen component and turning it into a blob in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

what I am trying to achieve is to have a component which is not visible to the user at any point, then turn it into an image and then get it to the user's clipboard. This is what I have right now.

```
  const generateImage = () => {
    const component = document.getElementById("component");
    if (component) {
      toBlob(component)
        .then(function (blob: any) {
          const textBlob: any = new Blob(["I am a string"], {
            type: "text/plain",
          });

          navigator.clipboard
            .write([
              new ClipboardItem({
                "image/png": blob,
                "text/plain": textBlob,
              }),
            ])
            .catch((e) => console.log(e));
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  };
```

It works fine when the component is in my sight (even though the image came out kind of shifted to the right? but this probably has to do with my styling), but when I tried something like

```
position: absolute;
left: -1000%;
```

It would leave me with an empty clipboard.

I have stumbled upon something like an OffscreenCanvas but I have no idea how to use it properly and maybe there is a cleaner solution to my problem.

Comment: You should use a ref instead of `document.getElementById()` but I fail to see how the position of the canvas could influence the toBlob function.

Comment: I am not a webdev myself, just trying to make it work somehow. I am using html-to-image and position of the component basically changes how the blob looks like. I'll give ref a try in a sec, maybe it changes something

Comment: Also if I set visibility:hidden; I get an empty image too

Answer (score 0):

I kind of fixed the issue by using another library to first convert the div into a canvas and then such canvas into a blob.

Comment: Could you give which other lib you've used please?

Comment: Yes, I first turned the offscreen component with html2canvas to canvas and then used on it the built in toBlob function.